# Force Laravel FormRequest to fail

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In my custom Request, in the rules method, I'm checking a few things before returning the rules array.

I would like to make the validation fail as soon as I found some errors I can't check by the default validation rules.

So I would like to have something like this:

```
public function rules() {
  $rules = [
     'first_parameter' => 'required'
  ];

  if( someErrorCondition ) {
     // here i would like to make the rules method always fail the validation
  }

  return $rules;
}
```

What's the best approach to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [custom validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the complete wrong method.

Your rules list is a basic list of rules to perform validation on.

For additional logic, either add it into the controller (at the expense of your sanity later on), or use a [custom rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules).

If you need to restrict users based on permissions, etc. then use the `authorize` method.

Comment: yeah that's the other thing I was wondering: if I was taking the right approach. Thanks

Comment: I also completely forgot you can register a custom rule, too. Whoops.

Comment: yeah @Amelia, I think the custom rule is the way to go